# Nullreference exception c# wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception, isolatedstorage

I'm getting the same error when I'm trying to delete my save files. The problem is, I've successfully created the save files, but the error indicates that there isn't any save files at all when i tried deleting them. However, they do keep track of how many save files i've save. If possible, is anyone free to check my codes? I'm willing to send my app.

The nullreference exception is being thrown over here:

LoadFile.cs

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewDiskModel model =  this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as ViewDiskModel;
        int m_iSelectedLoad = lstBox1.SelectedIndex;
        if (m_iSelectedLoad >= 0)
        {
            model.DeleteSelectedFiles.Execute(null);

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Files Successfully Deleted");
    }
```

Below are the codes responsible for the above codes to work.

AddFileModel.cs

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1.Model
{
    public class AddFileModel : ModelBase
    {
        private string _filename;
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._filename;
            }
            set
            {
                this._filename = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }

        }

        private string _filetext10;
        public string FileText10
        {
            get
            {
                return this._filetext10;
            }
            set
            {
                this._filetext10 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FileText10");
            }
        }

        private ICommand _saveFile;
        public ICommand SaveFile
        {
            get
            {
                this._saveFile = this._saveFile ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnSaveFile);
                return this._saveFile;
            }
        }

         private ICommand _readSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand ReadSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._readSelectedFiles = this._readSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnReadSelected);
                return this._readSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private void OnSaveFile()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName))
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                        store.DeleteFile(FileName);

                    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store)))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(this.FileText1 + this.FileText2 + this.FileText3 + this.FileText4 + this.FileText5 + this.FileText6 + this.FileText7 + this.FileText8 + this.FileText9 + this.FileText10);
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnReadSelected()
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (store.FileExists(FileName))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store)))

                        {
                            string textData = this.FileText1 + this.FileText2 + this.FileText3 + this.FileText4 + this.FileText5 + this.FileText6 + this.FileText7 + this.FileText8 + this.FileText9 + this.FileText10;
                         textData = reader.ReadLine(); 

                        }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

ViewDiskModel.cs

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1.Model
{
    public class FileItem : ModelBase
    {

        public bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return this.isChecked; }
            set
            {
                this.isChecked = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }    

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileText { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewDiskModel : ModelBase
    {
        private IsolatedStorageFile currentStore;
        public IsolatedStorageFile Store
        {
            get
            {
                this.currentStore = this.currentStore ?? IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                return this.currentStore;
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
        {
            get
            {
                this._files = this._files ?? this.LoadFiles();
                return this._files;
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
        {
            ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();

            foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames())
                files.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filePath });
            return files;
        }

        private ICommand _deleteSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand DeleteSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._deleteSelectedFiles = this._deleteSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnDeleteSelected);
                return this._deleteSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private ICommand _readSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand ReadSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._readSelectedFiles = this._readSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnReadSelected);
                return this._readSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private void OnDeleteSelected()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            List<FileItem> removedItems = new List<FileItem>();
            foreach (var item in this.Files)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked)
                    if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
                    {
                        storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
                        removedItems.Add(item);
                    }
            }

            foreach (var item in removedItems)
                this.Files.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

ModelBase.cs

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1.Model
{
    public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs eargs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, eargs);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand.cs

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1.Model
{
    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action command;
        public Action Command
        {
            get { return this.command; }
        }
        private Func<bool> canExecuteCommand;

        public DelegateCommand(Action cmd, Func<bool> canexecute)
        {
            this.canExecuteCommand = canexecute;
            this.command = cmd;
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action cmd)
        {
            this.command = cmd;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this.canExecuteCommand != null)
                return this.canExecuteCommand();

            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this.command != null)
                this.command();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Edited: (This is what i add in my XAML of the load page)

ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" Margin="0,42,0,115" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="lstBox1" DataContext="{StaticResource vmDiskModel}">
                ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    DataTemplate >
                        CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding FileName}" />
                    /DataTemplate>
                /ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            /ListBox>

Comment: Can you provide the code leads to error?

Comment: Please, post the code... without it it is impossible to give any answer at all.

Comment: @user: or not. Narrow it down a bit. Nobody's going to read all that code.

Comment: sorry about it, was afraid you guys needed to see the codes.

Comment: Most of that code isn't relevant to the question.  Maybe tell us where the exception is being thrown, and get rid of all the code that isn't related.

Comment: Ok, i've added the code which the exception is being thrown. The codes below are the main codes which handles all the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about your application, or reading all code snippets you posted, I'm pretty sure you would want to add a null-check to the `button2_Click` method:

```
ViewDiskModel model =  this.LayoutRoot.DataContext as ViewDiskModel;
```

Basically what this does, is assign the `ViewDiskModel` to `model` if `this.LayoutRoot.DataContext` is of the type `ViewDiskModel`. If it is of any other type, it will assign `null` to `model.

Try checking if `model == null` after that line.

Comment: how do i check? What i've got is:

this.DataContext - "Could not evaluate expression"
Files.Count - "The name 'Files' does not exist in the current context"

However, i've got the files listed o n the listbox. So i'm not sure why is it still a null value.

Comment: What `DataContext` are you assigning your data to? If you're setting the `DataContext` at the `ListBox` level, `LayoutRoot.DataContext` would not be set.

Comment: 'DataContext - "Could not evaluate expression"' means null DataContext. It means you do not set it.

Comment: @Jan Slodicka: in WPF, an element can inherit the `DataContext` from its parent - making "you do not set it" a bit vague.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis

How do i go about it then?

Comment: Instead of referencing `this.LayoutRoot.DataContext` (the `DataContext` of the `LayoutRoot` element) you could reference the ListBox' `DataContext` (`lstBox1.DataContext`).

Comment: i've edited the question, feel free to checkthe XAMl for the load page. It might be the problem.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis

It's still not deleting, even if there are no error pop ups anymore.


        'private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewDiskModel model = lstBox1.DataContext as ViewDiskModel;
            
            int m_iSelectedLoad = lstBox1.SelectedIndex;
            if (m_iSelectedLoad >= 0)
            {
                model.DeleteSelectedFiles.Execute(null);
    

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Files Successfully Deleted");
        }'

Comment: anyone can teach me how to comment the codes format too? i'm new at this.

Comment: Is there still a `NullReferenceException` or is this a different issue? As far as I know you can't format comments other than inline comments using backticks.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis

They didn't give that error anymore, but it still doesn't delete the file either.

Comment: As the original error is fixed, I suggest you make a new question "ViewDiskModel.DeleteSelectedFiles.Execute(null) does not delete any files" and provide your information there, so the community can help out instead of just me (and I don't know the `ViewDiskModel` class)

Comment: here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411090/viewdiskmodel-deleteselectedfiles-executenull-does-not-delete-any-files-help