# ViewDiskModel.DeleteSelectedFiles.Execute(null) does not delete any files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception, isolatedstorage, delete-file

My App wouldn't delete the save files on the loading page in the isolated storage. The codes for the delete and the ViewDiskModel.cs class are below:

LoadingPage.cs

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewDiskModel model = lstBox1.DataContext as ViewDiskModel;

        int m_iSelectedLoad = lstBox1.SelectedIndex;
        if (m_iSelectedLoad >= 0)
        {
            model.DeleteSelectedFiles.Execute(null);


        }

        MessageBox.Show("Files Successfully Deleted");
    }
```

ViewDiskModel.cs:

```
 public class FileItem : ModelBase
    {

        public bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return this.isChecked; }
            set
            {
                this.isChecked = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }


        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileText { get; set; }



    }

    public class ViewDiskModel : ModelBase
    {
        private IsolatedStorageFile currentStore;
        public IsolatedStorageFile Store
        {
            get
            {
                this.currentStore = this.currentStore ?? IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                return this.currentStore;
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
        {
            get
            {
                this._files = this._files ?? this.LoadFiles();
                return this._files;
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
        {
            ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();

            foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames())
                files.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filePath });
            return files;
        }

        private ICommand _deleteSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand DeleteSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._deleteSelectedFiles = this._deleteSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnDeleteSelected);
                return this._deleteSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private ICommand _readSelectedFiles;
        public ICommand ReadSelectedFiles
        {
            get
            {
                this._readSelectedFiles = this._readSelectedFiles ?? new DelegateCommand(this.OnReadSelected);
                return this._readSelectedFiles;
            }
        }

        private void OnDeleteSelected()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            List<FileItem> removedItems = new List<FileItem>();
            foreach (var item in this.Files)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked)
                    if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
                    {
                        storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
                        removedItems.Add(item);
                    }
            }

            foreach (var item in removedItems)
                this.Files.Remove(item);
        }

        private void OnReadSelected()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            List<FileItem> removedItems = new List<FileItem>();
            foreach (var item in this.Files)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked)
                    if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
                    {
                        storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
                        removedItems.Add(item);
                    }
            }

            foreach (var item in removedItems)
                this.Files.Remove(item);
        }


    }
```

LoadingPage.XAML:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" DataContext="{StaticResource vmDiskModel}">
            <Button Content="Back" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,530,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
            <Button Content="Delete" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,530,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button2_Click" />
            <Button Content="Continue" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296,530,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button3_Click" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="PLease select a save file to load." VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" Margin="0,42,0,115" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="lstBox1" DataContext="{StaticResource vmDiskModel}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code? any errors? if so, what? and on which line?

Comment: @Matt Lacey - no errors, it just isn't doing what it should do, deleting the save files. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @lala and when you step through the code does it call `onDeleteSelected()`?

Comment: Not sure how to check, but looking at the codes, I believe it is calling that method via the DeleteSelectedFiles ICommand.

Comment: That looks like what it's doing but without a complete example it's hard to say what's wrong. Set a break point in the event handler and step through the code (F9). If you run the code as is what happens? do you get the messagebox displayed?

Comment: @Matt Lacey - will have to continue tmr, i hope you will be keeping up with this, i have to solve this problem no matter what. And i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Matt Lacey - nothing is happening. I've tried to breakpoint and apparently no error message is shown and the application still isn't deleting my files.

Comment: Edited the question, added XAML codes for teh loading page. I hope you guyz will know how i showed the data on the loading page.

Comment: There's too much missing here to easily recreate your issue wihtout more from you. Provide a minimimal complete example which demonstrates the issue. Include all dependencies! I've taken the code you provided and added MVVMLight instead of whatever you're using for the ModelBase & DelegateCommand and I get the command firing but there are no files to delete.

Comment: @Matt Lacey - I've got a few more class files that is linked. Would you like me to post those in the question as well?

Comment: @lala create a working project which demonstrates the issue. Zip it up and then post a link to it.

Comment: @Matt Lacey - the codes i used is based on this source code i got online. You can refer to it. There area few errors in it as well which i'm having problems with. https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bafa39a62a57009c&sc=documents&id=BAFA39A62A57009C%21537#
Would be glad if you're able to help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code I get a `NullReferenceException` on line 33 in MainPage.xaml.cs
This is because you referenced the DataContext of `this.LayoutRoot` but had never set this. You had in fact set the DataContext of `ContentPanel`.
Line 32 should therefore be:

```
ViewDiskModel model = this.ContentPanel.DataContext as ViewDiskModel;
```

Additionally:
The view model was unaware of which items had been checked as you were using the default `OneWay` binding of properties. You need to change this to `TwoWay` so that changes in the UI are reflected back to the view model.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding FileName}" />
```

With these two changes the selected files are deleted.

Other issues:

- There appears to be some issue around the creation of multiple files one after the other such that only one gets created at a time, but I didn't look into this.
- You are not calling `Dispose()` (or using `using` directives) when working with `IsolatedStorageFile` which implements `IDisposable`.
- The code says it has deleted the files even if there aren't any selected or to delete.
- The app tries to display the IsolatedStorage quota but this concept doesn't exist on the phone. There is no quota whihc is why it shows the maximum value for a 64bit integer regardless of the size of the disk in the phone.
- And possibly more...?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do i go around calling the dispose()? I can solve the part where the code says it has deleted the files if there are no files to delete. And there's another issue where i have to re-run the app to make the saved files appear on the list.